# The annihilator of $n(2^n)\sin({n\pi \over 2})$

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have to solve this problem:

$y(n+2)-y(n)=n(2^n)\sin({n\pi \over 2})$

And I know the annihilator of $n(2^n) = (E-2)^2$, but I don't know how I should find the other part of the annihilator.

$y_p(n)=c_0+nc_1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not so familiar with applying annihilators to recurrence relations, but I found the idea interesting and did some reading. I'm fairly sure I have a solution, but it may not be the simplest.

Use Euler's formula ($ e^{i x} = \cos{x} + i \sin{x} $) to derive a more useful expression for $\sin(x)$ as follows:

$ e^{-i x} = \cos{-x} + i \sin{-x} = \cos{x} - i \sin{x} $

Hence $ e^{i x} - e^{-i x} = (\cos{x} + i \sin{x}) - (\cos{x} - i \sin{x}) = 2i \sin(x) $

$ \therefore \sin{x} = \frac{e^{i x} - e^{-i x}}{2i} $

Now, applying the new expression, we have:

$$ \sin{\frac{n \pi}{2}} = \frac{e^{i \frac{n \pi}{2}} - e^{-i \frac{n \pi}{2}}}{2 i} = \frac{(e^{i \frac{\pi}{2}})^n - (e^{-i \frac{\pi}{2}})^n}{2 i} = \frac{i^n - (-i)^n}{2 i} $$

And thus that $ n 2^n \sin{\frac{n \pi}{2}} = n 2^n \frac{i^n - (-i)^n}{2 i} = \frac{n}{2i}(2^n i^n - 2^n (-i)^n) = \frac{n}{2i}(2i)^n - \frac{n}{2i}(-2i)^n$

Which has annihilator $ (E - 2i)^2 (E + 2i)^2  = (E^2 + 4)^2$

Comment: Thank you, but the first formula you use, isn't that formula for sinus hyperbolicus? $\sinh(x)=\dfrac{(e^x-e^{-x}{2}$

Comment: @arnaud No, they just look very similar. There is a relationship between them: $ \sinh(i x) = i \sin(x) $ that confers to sinh most of it's nice properties.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! I never used Euler's formula in that way. We didn't see many examples from this part of the chapter either. It is indeed maybe not the simplest way.

Comment: @arnaud No problem. I've made a small edit to make it clearer how the expression for $\sin(x)$ is obtained.

Comment: $(e^(iπ/2))^n=i^n$ I don't really understand this part...

Comment: @arnaud It's from Euler's formula again: $e^{i \frac{\pi}{2}} = \cos{\frac{\pi}{2}} + i \sin{\frac{\pi}{2}} = 0 + i \cdot 1$.

Comment: Oh ok! It's obvious! I need to get some sleep I think. Again thank you for the help, it was very useful.